# Storing a list of results in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My code takes a list of numbers and find it's divisors. Now, let's say I have a list [12,15,20]. Now, as I go through each element in the list, my aim is to store all the divisors of 12,15 and 20 in separate lists so I could reference back to them later

E.g.,

divisors of 4 are `1, 2, 4`

divisors of 12 are `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12`

So, the result should look like `[[1,2,4],[1,2,3,4,6,12]]`

Now, after finishing finding divisors of 4, append them to a list. Then store that list in the 1st index of new list called M. Then, go on to find divisors of 12, append them to a list and store that list at the 2nd index of list M

However, I am not able to do this and this is my attempt and a visualizer to help with understanding what's going on in the code http://goo.gl/InJxV3 :

```
def fn(N):
    result = []
    G = []
    if type(N) is list:                          #checks input for list type
        for i in N:                          #for elements in input. e.g., 12,15,20
            for j in range(1,i+1):           #j is the numbers that we're going to divide i with
                if(i%j == 0 and i >= j):     #checks if remainder is 0, if it is, then j is a divisor/multiple of i
                    result.append(j)         #appends j to list result
            G.append([result])               # <----- NOT RIGHT.Attempting to create a new list to store result.
return print(G[:])

fn([4,12,15])
```

Will be glad to get some guidance, help, advice. Also, I would prefer not to use the zip() function.

Comment: what's the problem with appending lists to the another list

Comment: @minitoto sorry I don't understand your question. The problem is, when i append them to another list, the old list has divisors from the previous i element e.g., 4 is in the list already and appending divisors of 12 to that old list is not what I am trying to do, I want to separate them. Also, check out the visualizer, hopefully it helps

Comment: append lists to a new list, and it's going to be list of lists, isn't it what you want?

Comment: @misheekoh: you should add an example of your desired results to your question.  Starting with [12, 15, 20] you want [[1, [1, 3, [1, 2, 4], 12], [1, 5, 3, 15], [1, [1, 5, 2, 10], 2, 20]]?

Comment: you didn't ask for a shorter or better solution, but i added the shorter one, since you removed accepted from my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what you want:

```
def fn(N):
    result = []
    if isinstance(N, list):
        for i in N:
            G = []
            for j in range(1,i+1):
                if not i%j and i >= j:
                    G.append(j)
            result.append(G)
    return result
```

Or if you want short version:

```
def fn(n):
    return [[j for j in range(1,i+1) if not i % j and i >= j] 
            for i in n if isinstance(n, list)]  

print fn([4, 12, 15])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12], [1, 3, 5, 15]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a function to find the factors of all of the numbers in a list of integers, first write a function to find the factors of one number:

```
def factor(n):
    factors = set()

    for x in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            factors.add(x)
            factors.add(n//x)

    return sorted(factors)
```

Now that you can find the factors of a single number, you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) to apply it to a list of numbers:

```
map(factor, [4, 12, 15])
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[factor(n) for n in [4, 12, 15]]
```

Both of these methods return the following:

> [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12], [1, 3, 5, 15]]

If you would like to, you can make either one of them into a function:

```
def factor_list(arr):
    return map(factor, arr)

factor_list([4, 12, 15])
```

As you can see, breaking the initial problem down from finding the factor of a list of numbers to finding the factor of one number makes the overall problem much easier and the solution much simpler.

### EDIT 1

*The following is an explanation of why I used `n//x` as opposed to just `n/x`, as per the OP's request.*

`//` is the [floor division](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-floor-division) operator in Python. It is essentially equivalent to dividing the two numbers and then calling [`math.floor()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.floor) on the quotient. The reason we need to do this is because `n/x` would use "true division," which as you said, returns a float. Since we are looking for integral factors, it only makes sense to force the numbers to be ints.

If you really wanted to, you could replace my `factor` function with the algorithm you used in your question without changing the behavior of the program:

```
def factor(i):
    result = []
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        if i % j == 0:
            result.append(j)
    return result
```

Or, the shorter equivalent:

```
def factor(i):
    return [j for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0]
```

However, the algorithm I used is more efficient, as it only needs to check up until the square root of the number being factored.

### EDIT 2

I see from some other answers that you are possibly looking for the shortest solution:

```
fn=lambda a:map(lambda i:[j for j in range(1, i+1)if i%j==0],a)
```

I believe I win with the above, 63 character one-liner :). Although this solution is very short, I believe my first solution is better, as it is much more readable. Remember, shorter isn't always better!

Comment: That is indeed very helpful! I'm looking to implement that into my code. Thank you!

Comment: what does `factors.add(n//x)` do? With 1 `/`, it started returning floats and is there  a name for this function? also, is there a way I could reference back to the original number let's say 4 from list[0]

Comment: I just added a response to your first question to my answer. Not sure what you mean by your second question. Could you try rephrasing it to make it clearer?

Comment: @misheekoh Whoops, forgot to tag you in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

- You never create a new list.
  This should be inside the loop: `result = []`
- `return print(G[:])` You either print, or return. Mixing them doesn't make sense, as `print` returns nothing (`None`).

Comment: Actually initializing the result outside of the list makes sense; but he (or she) should initialize a new list 'entry = []' at the beginning of the loop then replace the current entry for that item in the results with the entry at the end:  'result[i]=entry'

Comment: @KarolyHorvath hey! I got it! that's nice, but I may want the result to be a global variable, I will look at JimDennis' way too!

Comment: Don't. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def fn(N):
    result = []
    G = []
    if type(N) is list:                          #checks input for list type
        for i in N:                          #for elements in input. e.g., 12,15,20
            for j in range(1,i+1):           #j is the numbers that we're going to divide i with
                if(i%j == 0 and i >= j):     #checks if remainder is 0, if it is, then j is a divisor/multiple of i
                    result.append(j)         #appends j to list result
            G.append(result)
            result = []
    print(G)
    return G

fn([4,12,15])
```